# How to update multiple document at once with mongoDB based on "generic" condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I'm working with node and MongoDB. I have an array of object that I'd like to update (or insert) in a collection.
I know if one of this object exist based on the property `game_id`.

Here is my array simplified:

```
[{ game_id: 10, foobar: "abc" },
 { game_id: 51, foobar: "def" },
 { game_id: 75, foobar: "ghi" }]
```

I managed it with a loop `for` but I'd like do all the update/insert on a single operation.

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < boardgames.length; i += 1) {
    boardgame = boardgames[i];
    if (boardgame.hasOwnProperty('game_id')) {
        db.collection('boardgames_debug').update({ game_id: boardgame.game_id}, 
        boardgame, 
        { upsert: true }, //insert if not exist
        callbackUpset);
    }
}
```

I saw that you can update multiple lines in one operation based on the argument `multi` of `.update()`. But I don't know how to the write the query...

Do you know if it's possible to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this in one query.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

Comment: 'multi' updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria. It does not  update/insert multiple documents based on multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

I hope below helps you:

```
var bulkWriteOperation = db.car.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
    bulkWriteOperation.find( {game_id: boardgame.game_id} ).upsert().update({$setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 0, inStock: true },$currentDate: { lastModified: true },$set: { status: "I", points: "0" }});
}
bulkWriteOperation.execute();
```

For more inform check mongodb docs for bulk operation upsert for update() method. This is precisely you need.